# New volume in ec2 instance not reflecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, volumes

I have a volume of 250 gb initially in one of my ec2 instance. I have increased the volume to 300gb. I could able to see that 300gb using the below command
[image]

But when i do df-h command i could not see the 300gb volume. Please help i am new to AWS
[image]

Comment: did you `resize2fs` ?

Comment: Yes i did i am getting this error
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-172-31-3-165: Resource temporarily unavailable
resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/xvda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New volumes should be formatted to be accessible. Resized existing volumes should also be modified (resized) from the inside of the operating system.

The general information on how to do this safely (e.g. with snapshots) is given in the following AWS documentation:

- [Making an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)
- [Extending a Linux file system after resizing a volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Based on the discussion in comments, two commands were used to **successfully solve the problem**:

- sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
- sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1

Comment: I tried to extend the partition by using sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
Its showing the below error
 Resource temporarily unavailable
CHANGED: partition=1 start=2048 old: size=524285919 end=524287967 new: size=629143519,end=629145567

Comment: @HarnishKumar Can you clarify it this is totally new volume, or it was existing volume that was working fine. But then when you extended it stopped working?

Comment: It was an existing volume not working when i extend

Comment: @HarnishKumar I see. This is `root` volume.

Comment: @HarnishKumar I did a quick check on my ubuntu instance, and ` CHANGED` means that the resize was successful. Did you check `lsblk` again?

Comment: lsblk i could see the 300gb 
xvda    202:0    0  300G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  250G  0 part /
But when i do df-h i could not
udev            468M     0  468M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  5.6M   93M   6% /run
/dev/xvda1      243G  243G     0 100% /
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/9066
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215142/discussion-between-harnish-kumar-and-marcin).

Answer (score 12):

Let's solve step by step

1. After increasing the EBS volume size, connect to your instance over SSH to check the EBS volume size.

> ```
> ssh ubuntu@<Public IP> -i <Key Pair>
> ```

2. Now use the df command to list all the filesystems mounted on your disk.

> sudo df -hT

3. I hope you are seeing that The root filesystem size (/dev/xvda1) is still (X GB here X={Your EC2 storage size}), and its type is ext4. Now use the lsblk command in the terminal to check whether the disk has an extended partition.

> sudo lsblk

4. The root volume (/dev/xvda) has a partition (/dev/xvda1). The size of the volume is 20 GB, but the size of the partition is still X GB. Now use the growpart command in the terminal to extend the partition size.

> sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1

5. Again use the lsblk command in the terminal to verify if the partitions size extended.

> sudo lsblk

6. So far, the volume size and the partition size have been extended. Use the df command to check if the root filesystem has been extended or not.

> sudo df -hT

*The size of the root filesystem is still X GB, and it needs to be extended. To extend different types of filesystems, different commands are used.*

7. In order to extend an ext4 filesystem, the resize2fs command is used.

> sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1

8. Now again, list all the filesystems on your EC2 instance using the df command.

> sudo df -hT

I hope you are seeing the changes after running the **resize2fs** command, the size of the filesystem is increased.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the EC2 instance & verify mounted point:`df -h`
2. Then identify the filesystem: `df -T`
3. Resize the File System:For xfs: `sudo xfs_growfs /dev/nvme0n1p1`
   For ext4:`sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1`.

Replace `/dev/nvme0n1p1` with appropriate device identifier for your system.

4. Now verify the mounted point. In some cases, a restart the instance: `sudo reboot`